# Unified a data based on dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have this query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bookings.start_at, '%m/%d/%Y') as "Date",
   CASE WHEN payment.type = "CASH"  THEN sum(payment.amount)  end as "Cash" ,
   CASE WHEN payment.type = "Credit" THEN sum(payment.amount)  end as "Credit" 
from orders
inner join bookings on bookings.id = orders.booking_id
inner join payment on payment.order_id = orders.id
where (bookings.start_at BETWEEN '2022-03-09' AND '2022-03-09 23:59:00')
group by  payment.type;
```

And it returning like this

```
Date       |      Cash | Credit
2022/03/09 |   NULL    | NULL
2022/03/09 |   2000    | NULL
2022/03/09 |   NULL    | 5000
```

What i want to achieve is like this

```
Date       |      Cash | Credit
2022/03/09 |   2000    | 5000
```

i already tried  **GROUP BY** for start_at but it return a different kind of time but same date

Comment: You want to sum per date, not by payment type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bookings.start_at, '%m/%d/%Y') as `Date`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment.type = "CASH" 
                THEN payment.amount 
                ELSE 0 
                END) as `Cash`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment.type = "Credit" 
                THEN payment.amount 
                ELSE 0 
                END) as `Credit`
from orders
inner join bookings on bookings.id = orders.booking_id
inner join payment on payment.order_id = orders.id
where bookings.start_at BETWEEN '2022-03-09' AND '2022-03-09 23:59:00'
group by 1;
```